# In .factory how to access $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Probably a newbie's question. I am trying *not* to hard-code `xsrfHeaderName` and `xsrfCookieName`, but how to get them from `$httpProvider`?

```
.factory('XSRFInterceptor', function($cookies) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      config.headers[$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName] =
      $cookies[$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName];
      return config;
    }
  }
})

.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('XSRFInterceptor');
})
```

After trial-and-error-ed a number of things, it seems that I still need to learn more about angularjs. Appreciate a jump-start.

Comment: You are trying to use $httpProvider in your factory without injecting it. You could try adding that in, I have a code snippet that I use for this if that doesn't work after that.

Comment: @ribsies, thanks for your response. As a part of my trial-and-error, I had tried `.factory('XSRFInterceptor', function($cookies, $httpProvider) {`, but gotten `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <- $httpProvider <- XSRFInterceptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state`. I am not sure how to do the injection right. Can you share your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so i'm pretty sure you can't inject $httpProvider into a factory. I'm not sure what property you are trying to put in your headers but this is how I do this sort of thing and it works great.

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$window', 
  function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
    return {
      request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers.Authorization = $cookies.Authorization;
        return config;
      }
    };
}]);
```

Something like that, basically just don't use $httpProvider.

Comment: Appreciate your code snippet. You're right that `$httpProvider` can't be injected into its interceptors. I realized that would generate a circular dependency. Being a `$http` interceptor, is it possible to access the `xsrfCookieName` and `xsrfCookieName` (right at your `Authorization`), which are provided by `$httpProvider`? I can't seem to find them in the `config` object.

Answer (score 0):

As of AngularJS 1.4.3, it just needs a line of dynamic injection:

```
.factory('XSRFInterceptor', function($cookies, $injector) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      var $http = $injector.get('$http');
      var xsrfToken = $cookies.get($http.defaults.xsrfCookieName);
      if (xsrfToken)
        config.headers[$http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName] = xsrfToken;
      return config;
    }
  }
}
```